Event registration fails with an error
Event registration fails with below error
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected token ">" in Smarty->_eval() (line 610 of /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(2018) : eval()'d code).

The error only appears when send confirmation email is set for an event.

If you are on CiviCRM 5.70.x then it's a known issue which is fixed in the recent version. You can either apply the below patch and do db changes or upgrade CiviCRM to 5.72.x

Patch file CRM/Event/DAO/Event.php

diff --git a/CRM/Event/DAO/Event.php b/CRM/Event/DAO/Event.php
index 32de78e3325c..de7379737b04 100644
--- a/CRM/Event/DAO/Event.php
+++ b/CRM/Event/DAO/Event.php
@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@
  *
  * Generated from xml/schema/CRM/Event/Event.xml
  * DO NOT EDIT.  Generated by CRM_Core_CodeGen
- * (GenCodeChecksum:d63c53d10f2e09895a19061ea9d51093)
+ * (GenCodeChecksum:193894c0362eb3c7360ad8245e303fcf)
  */
 
 /**
@@ -542,7 +542,7 @@ class CRM_Event_DAO_Event extends CRM_Core_DAO {
   /**
    * Number of hours prior to event start date to allow self-service cancellation or transfer.
    *
-   * @var int|string|null
+   * @var int|string
    *   (SQL type: int)
    *   Note that values will be retrieved from the database as a string.
    */
@@ -1994,6 +1994,7 @@ public static function &fields() {
           'type' => CRM_Utils_Type::T_INT,
           'title' => ts('Self-service Cancellation or Transfer Time'),
           'description' => ts('Number of hours prior to event start date to allow self-service cancellation or transfer.'),
+          'required' => TRUE,
           'usage' => [
             'import' => FALSE,
             'export' => FALSE,


Run below query

UPDATE civicrm_event SET selfcancelxfer_time = 0 WHERE selfcancelxfer_time IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE civicrm_event MODIFY COLUMN selfcancelxfer_time int(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL COMMENT 'Number of hours prior to event start date to allow self-service cancellation or transfer.';




Clear CiviCRM cache

HTH
Pradeep

Thanks Pradeep, this patch works for CiviCRM 5.70.2

Thank you Pradeep, we upgraded CiviCRM to 5.72.3

Thanks, but this is NOT working using v 5.70.1.  Any suggestions?  My plan was to update to ESR 5.75.1 when it comes out.
